# EMR: unable to run steps in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I am trying to run several EMR steps in parallel. 
I saw other questions regarding this issue on SO, as well as googled options. 
so things i have tried:

- Configure CapacityScheduler with set of queues
- Configure FairScheduler
- Try to use AWS data pipelines with PARALLEL_FAIR_SCHEDULING, PARALLEL_CAPACITY_SCHEDULING

this wasn't worked for me, yarn was created all queues properly, and submission was done on different queues. But EMR still ran just a single step at once (one step was RUNNING rest of them PENDING)

I also saw from one of the answers that step is meant to be sequential, but you can put several jobs inside single step. I wasn't managed to find a way to do this, and according to UI there is no option for this.

I wasn't tried to submit jobs to yarn cluster directly [Submit Hadoop Jobs Interactively](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/interactive-jobs.html), i wanted to submit jobs from AWS API, and i havent found a way to do this from API

This is my configuration for CapacityScheduler [CapacityScheduler](https://gist.github.com/pilgrimkst/a477f28fcc709c59fe0e5856fcba9ad6)

This is steps configuration [StepsConfiguration](https://gist.github.com/pilgrimkst/8092f6c1392745525175022a464417dd)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. It's not designed to work like that out of the box. You might to do this in a serverless fashion using AWS Step Functions. You can create the entire workflow in AWS Step Functions and interact with Spark on Amazon EMR through Apache Livy (per example). The list of choices is wide but you need in all cases some kind of orchestrator (Oozie, Airflow, Livy isn't an orchestrator but it might do the job when used with Step Functions)

Comment: This said, I'm closing the question as being broad to answer.

Comment: @eliasah thanks, so as far as i understood EMR steps are useless if parallel execution is required, the only way to use EMR is bootstrap spark cluster and use tools that provides API over spark, or yarn cluster directly?

Comment: Well, useless is a big word. You can per example add a step running parallel spark jobs using Oozie.

Comment: @eliasah thanks, i will take a look on Oozie

Comment: I’m not saying that Oozie is the only or best solution. I just gave it as an exemple because it can be shipped easily with EMR.

Comment: @eliasah we ended up launching a script as emr step, and do all parallel work inside this script. It's not giving much info to reason about failures or work status, but it works for us

Answer (score 1):

Might be late, but hope this would be helpful.

Spark provides an option that specifying whether the caller (step) will wait or not for spark application completion after submission. You can set this value as `false` then, AWS emr step will submit and will return immediately.

`spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion: "false"`

[image]